# Cycles | Boolean modifier - Color Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I'm making a Minecraft character and for the face I made holes with the boolean modifier; inside the head everything is grey but I want to have the colors of the front side of the head. I want to be able to modify the cubes which cut the holes so I don't want to apply the modifier.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Boolean mod will place whatever materials are on the mesh used to modify the object ***provided that they are also included in the modified object (i.e. the big cube)***.  Only colors that are in the big cube will be received from the modifying mesh (the little cube).  You can see a dark green on the underside of the little cube but it is not applied to the cavity because the big cube does not contain that material.

[image]

So you *must* make your modifier mesh cube exactly the way you want your colors to appear in the head cavities.

Comment: thank you very much.